# Handling Button Clicks from a different Class

Tags: c#, class, event-handling

I have a Form with Button ButtonGo.

and I have a class which takes a button through its constructor, then handles its events:

```
public class HandlingClass
{//.......
Button go ;
    public HandlingClass(Button btn)
    {
        this.go = btn;
        this.go.Click += new EventHandler(this.go_Click);
    }
    //.....
    public void go_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //logic here

    }
```

What am I doing wrong, and why isn't the event being raised when I press the Button in the caller form?

Comment: Looks ok to me, you can remove the "this." in this.go_Click btw. Did you try just puting a MessageBox in the go_Click to see if your logic is causing the problem? Oh and try a lambda expression **this.go.Click += (s,e) =>{ MessageBox.Show("A");};**

Comment: I used a breakpoint to check if the eventhandler method is being reached. It turned out it is not. @Vajura  I did try the lambda expression with same results. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Does it work if you subscribe to this event on the form class where you use the button?

Comment: Adding a local (Inside the same form) eventhandler will handle the event correctly. However doing this: go.Click += new EventHandler(HC.go_click); also does nothing, and doesn't fire the event uppon clicking the button.

Comment: OK, is your HandlingClass a subclass?

Comment: No it is not. It does not inherit any other class

Comment: Dont know why it doesnt work then, try this http://pastebin.com/GnuUtVTQ works for me

Comment: Ok so i tried the exact same logic that @Vajura gave me, and it worked just fine. I just don't get it.

Comment: yea something in the code from HandlingClass class is causing this i think

Comment: I will look further into it. Anyway post your response and I'll mark it as an answer, thank you very much. @Vajura

Comment: Its ok we didnt fix the problem :)

Comment: @Vajura I deleted the Form i am using, then created a form from scratch and made it identical to my old form. It worked like a charm. Something must have went terribly wrong with the old form, which I wasn't able to pinpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me

```
public class HandlingClass
{
    Button go;
    public HandlingClass(Button btn)
    {
        go = btn;
        go.Click += go_Click;
    }

    void go_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and in your loaded event of the class having the button you just add the below code

```
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HandlingClass hc=new HandlingClass(**MyButton**);
}
```

**MyButton** should be the reference to your button.

Comment: The Form which contains the button initializes the class in its Load Method. as : HandlingClass hc = new HandlingClass(mybutton);

Comment: Try removing the "this" reference to refer the buttons.

Comment: no removing the this reference doesn't change anything.